# php codeigniter controllers with scrambled/uglified code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just inherited a codeigniter application and looking trough the source code all the controllers have scrambled code. Example:

```
<?php $_X='-8588104972344438462';vMASFkAm('MTExMTAxMDAwMTAxMDEwMDAwMDAwEMMTA=');*
```

Is there any way to get back the original code?

Is this something codeigniter specific?

I don't have much experience with codeigniter. Please help.

Comment: I agree with the answers below, this has nothing to do with Codeigniter, and is possibly the result of the site being hacked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have time and will, you can debug all that. See what each function outputs while making sure you replace any `eval`s with `echo`s, just to be on the safe side. The string parameter for that function looks like base64 encoded string, so you might want to decode that as well (or track where it's decoded in the code, and see the output). If it's not base64, it uses some more sophisticated algorithm where `x` and `w` seem like separators...

Unfortunately, unless you do it manually, variable by variable, function by function, etc... there's no way to get it back to the original state.

And, like the other answer said, this is in no way CodeIgniter-specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is not CodeIgniter related. Looks like obfuscated code -- likely due to an exploit of some kind. I'd be concerned this server has been compromised.

https://www.google.com/search?q=is+my+server+compromised

To search a little deeper, I'd start by grepping through the codebase looking for

```
function vMASFkAm(
```

to see what's there.